# CentOS 6.8 OpenSSL v1.0.1-fips NodeJS handshake

Tags: openssl, centos, node.js

I have installed nodejs (lastest v.7.x.x) on my CentOS 6.8 form binary package. I am trying to connect to a site that uses quite old TSLv1 encryption protocol. On handshake with that domain ( I use https module ) NodeJS fails with following error message:

```
Error: write EPROTO 140078368692000:error:14077438:SSL 
routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal 
error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:769:

    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1033:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:816:14)
```

And when I add secureProtocol option (setting it to TLSv1_method) I get:

```
   write EPROTO 140528424298272:error:14094438:SSL 
   routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal 
   error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 80
   140528424298272:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl 
   handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:659:
```

OpenSSL version (as if it would matter with binary package) on my machine currently has version:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

As far as I know NodeJS uses it's own binary package, so upgrade would rather not help (and I would like to avoid that if possible).

I've already checked changelog for OpenSSL and there seems not to be any issue that affects that specific build of OpenSSL (I meen handshake issue).

Comment: This can be anything like missing SNI extension when it is needed, site needing some weak cipher which is disabled by default, client certificate needed,... or simply a broken server. It's impossible to tell from these information. If the site is public available you might get more help if you include it into your question so that someone can reproduce your problem.

Comment: That alert means the _server_ thinks there is a problem. Best approach is to look for logs or similar data on the server to see what it thinks the problem is.

Comment: Alert number 80 is an internal error, I don't think this has anything to do with the server.

Comment: @KirillSinitski: yes, it is an internal error at the server side which is received by the client: `...ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error ...` means that the client has received a TLS alert from the server. Therefore logs at the server might help, if there are any with sufficient detail.

Comment: Neither of those helped. But you know what? TL;DR : The cause of all that seemed to be concurrency.


**Long version**


I have an API that limits requests 1000 each 10 minutes. It has no batch download, so I had to implement multiple concurrent requests (time of their execution did not matter to me at all - just to fit in 10 minute window).


When I've set concurrent requests limit to 1000 it failed with the error mentioned above.


But narrowing down concurrent connections to 100 solved that. Does openssl have some kind of bug?